# Is it possible to create this in pure html 5

Tags: jquery, html, css, effects

I need to create [this effect](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8698905/Untitled.jpg) in HTML "Colhemos ideias, semeamos futuro..."

Is this possible?

[image]

Basically, it's a white box with 0.7 opacity and a background image behind it. The text must be in the white box, but the letters need to act as a mask to allow the background image to show through them.

Comment: Don't think that is possible with just HTML and CSS. You may be able to achieve it with SVG, or Canvas, but that of course would require a Javascript library.

Comment: Have you an idea of an "not pure" html5 solution ? Even with SVG and Canvas I don't see anything practical in a general way.

Comment: @dystroy With SVG its possible. If it's practical, well, thats another story.

Comment: That screenshot, is it from an existing website? If so, you can learn a lot from looking at its source.

Comment: @MrLister I'm pretty much sure, this is just a transparent png...

Comment: This web site a photoshop and i need transform it. My idea id do it with only html, css and js, to make this much compatible possible.

Comment: For me pure html is only html and css.

Comment: For me, pure HTML doesn't involve CSS … since that is a separate specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a transparent PNG where it's the exact same width as its white box container.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/mAQe4/

I also chose to use a repeating transparent PNG image for the background of the white box to avoid any differences with the transparency between the text image and its container.

Alternatively, you can use `opacity: o.8` in `#content` and `#footer`

HTML:

```
<div id="content-wrap">
    <div id="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>

    <img id="the-image" src="http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/4051/62739191.png" alt="" />

    <div id="footer">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
html {
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/850/850') repeat top left;
}


#content-wrap {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#content,
#footer {
    background: url('http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/2733/21138012.png')repeat top left;
}

#the-image { width: 100%; display: block; }
```

A huge advantage of this method over others is that it ensures wide browser compatibility. Today's latest versions of Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and IE should all handle this the same way when using transparent PNGs. Also, if IE compatibility is a priority, there are ways to get this working for as far back as IE6:

- http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems
- http://allinthehead.com/retro/338/supersleight-jquery-plugin

Comment: Man "I love you" ;) you  maybe saved my life. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

This (theoretically) is possible with image-masks, which at the moment are still not part of the official standards. At the moment, masks are only available in webkit engines.

support: http://caniuse.com/#search=mask

example: http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/19/mask-image-text/

Other than that, out of the top of my head, I don't think it is possible with pure CSS+HTML5.

Regarding your example... I think that's just a transparent `.png`.